# How to generate different random number for the same variable

Tags: c++

I want to use a while loop to generate a random number for a variable to spell out a scrambled word. My problem is that my code generates a number that is random but repeats that number rather than using a new number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string wordList[5] = {"cool", "friend", "helpful", "amazing", 
"person"};
    srand(time(0));
    int rWord = rand() % 5 + 1;
    string randWord = wordList[rWord];
    int runs = 0;
    int wordLen = randWord.length();
    while(runs != wordLen){
        int ranLN = rand() % wordLen;
        char randLetter = randWord[ranLN];
        cout << randLetter;
        runs++;
}

return 0;
}
```

I expected my results to be a fully scrambled word, but I instead got repeated letters. For example, I got the word "friend" scrambled as "eennn".

Comment: Just that you are generating random numbers does not mean that they cannot repeat. If you roll a dice 6 times, it is not guaranteed that you get each number exactly once. It is fully possible (although not terribly likely) that the random numbers you generated were indeed `4, 4, 5, 5, 5`. I recommend taking a look at [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: Minor note: the `int rWord = rand() % 5 + 1` line means that `rWord` will be between 1 and 5 - you want it to be between 0 and 4, as those are the subscripts of your array. Remove the `+ 1` part of that line.

Comment: you are looking for `std::random_shuffle`

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` was deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17, but you can use `std::shuffle` instead.

Comment: @R_Kapp Actually, it appears that this happened, given that `friend` has 6 letters and `eennn` only five - one of the rolls seems to have gone into the terminating `\0`.

Comment: @user463035818, @Blaze while those advises are good, this probably is a homework assignment where he student should think through it, to understand the issue. Pointing to library functions is good for productive code and good to show the professor hat one read the manual,but for understanding the issue the approach in the question is good (one could also look at the `<random>` header instead of `srand()`/`rand()` etc., but probably the professor taught the C functions and maybe expects the understanding of the modulo operation)

Comment: Are you allowed to use library functions?

Comment: @johannes I prefer not to assume (even not the obvious). Imho if this is homework then OP should let us know what are the requirements (eg roll your own instead of use `std`). I would always advise a beginner to take a look at what `std` has to offer, not only for production code, if their homework/assignment has special requirments, then this has to be taken into account of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, the current range of `rWord` is `1,2,3,4,5` which must be fixed to `0,1,2,3,4`.
Thus I removed `+1` from it's initialization equation in the following answer.
In addition, `ranLN` can be duplicate thus you got repeated letters.

Then, a possible way is recursively shuffling all characters of `randWord` and output them after the while loop finished as follows.
The same algorithm is shown [**here**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) as an example:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d5pomXihhBAesqy3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::string wordList[5] = {"cool", "friend", "helpful", "amazing", "person"};

    srand(time(0));
    
    std::size_t rWord = rand() % 5;
    std::string randWord = wordList[rWord];

    std::size_t runs = 0;
    std::size_t wordLen = randWord.length();
    
    while(runs != wordLen)
    {
        std::swap(randWord[runs], randWord[rand() % wordLen]);        
        ++runs;
    }
    
    std::cout << randWord << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

BTW, although `rand()` should be usually implemented by a something better LCG,
but, for instance as noted in (my local) C++ standard draft n4687, **the algorithm used in `rand()` is completely compiler implementation defined**:

> **29.6.9 Low-quality random number generation [c.math.rand]**
>
> ```
> int rand();
> void srand(unsigned int seed);
> ```
>
> *... **rand**’s underlying algorithm is unspecified. Use of **rand** therefore continues to be non-portable, with unpredictable and oft-questionable quality and performance.*

Fortunately, in C++11 and over, we can use `<random>` to generate a guaranteed quality randomness.
Thus I recommend you to use them with `std::shuffle` as follows.
If you need more high-quality randomness, you can use `std::mt19937` instead of `std::minstd_rand`:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lE1y8R9RHhDPBkH2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string wordList[5] = {"cool", "friend", "helpful", "amazing", "person"};
    
    std::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());

    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dis(0, 4);
    std::size_t rWord = dis(gen);
    std::string randWord = wordList[rWord];

    std::shuffle(randWord.begin(), randWord.end(), gen);        
    std::cout << randWord << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion after generating all random words then using set data structure would make the random word unique.